# Apache Commons FTPClient issue - 425 Can't build data connection: Connection refused

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons, ftp-client

I am trying to connect a remote ftp server using Apache Commons FTP library, i am able to log into FTP server but after that i am not able to issue any command and getting following error when trying to retrieve file.

> 425 Can't build data connection: Connection refused.
> but I am facing no issue while login using MS-DOS command prompt.

Do anybody know what would be the issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012392/looking-for-help-diagnosing-server-socket-problem-with-ftp-transfer-using-apache

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing code this is a stab in the dark, but have you tried the following

```
client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

if you are uploading from a local machine to a remote FTP server. I remember I had a similar problem and doing the above worked